# How to generate a separate signed APK for each flavor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I am working on updating an Android app using Android Studio 3. The previous versions where created using Android Studio 2.

When I build the last version using Android Studio 2 two separate APKs have been created, one for each product flavor I configured. Now in Android Studio 3 the "Generate Signed APK" dialog only offers a "combined" flavor which creates a single APK containing both flavors:

**App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 42
        versionName "2.0.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "freemium", "free"
    productFlavors {
        MyApp {
            dimension "freemium"
        }
        MyAppFree {
            dimension "free"
            applicationId 'com.example.MyApp.Free'
        }
    }
}
```

- Select "Build/Generate Signed APK..." in Android Studio
- Enter my keystore password and click Next
- On the following page I can select the destination folder, the build type (release) and the flavors. While v2 offered both flavors here (MyApp and MyAppFree), v3 only offers MyApp-MyAppFree
- `app-MyApp-MyAppFree-release.apk` is created instead of `app-MyApp-release.apk` and `app-MyAppFree-release.apk`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the problem was caused by using different **flavor dimension**s for the two flavors. Gradle creates one assemble task for each dimension combination: `MyAppMyAppFree` in my case

I added the dimensions only to to silence the warning *"All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension"* when updating from Android Studio 2 to 3. Since I did not actually  used the dimensions the solution was to simply use one dimension for both flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        MyApp {
            dimension "default"
        }
        MyAppFree {
            dimension "default"
            applicationId 'com.example.MyApp.Free'
        }
    }
```